# Is the reputation graph real time?

Tags: discussion, reputation, reputation-history

I noticed that the `graph` view on the reputation tab does not update immediately. The `time` and the `post` view do show the recent changes in reputation.

But i noticed the bar for reputation earned on the 4th of August 2015 did not appear for most of the day. It had entries only for the previous day. To me it looks like reputation for that day gets updated on the graph only at the end of that day.

Which makes me wonder whether the reputation graph is real time ?

Comment: There's pretty much nothing on the site that's "real time". There's heavy caching (server- and client-side) to make the site work fast and not overload the servers.